# Resize canvas in D3

Tags: d3.js, html5-canvas, d3fc

I'm trying to combine these two charts.

- Candlestick https://d3fc.io/examples/series-canvas-candlestick/
- Canvas resizing https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-canvas-rescaled?collection=@d3/d3-zoom
- Codepen with a result https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/rNeyPrz

In some reason, line `const [x, y] = transform.apply(d)` always returns `NaN` for `[x, y]`. How do I apply transform to canvas if I want to pan and zoom it?

**Copy of codepen**

```
<d3fc-canvas use-device-pixel-ratio></d3fc-canvas>

const data = fc.randomFinancial()(50);

/*
const data = [
   {
      "date":Date.parse("2020-08-26T02:02:54.448Z"),
      "open":100,
      "high":100,
      "low":99.11436368738923,
      "close":99.11436368738923,
      "volume":1057
   },
   {
      "date":Date.parse("2020-08-27T02:02:54.448Z"),
      "open":99.11436368738923,
      "high":99.22642061121108,
      "low":98.6444086208441,
      "close":98.7908380643821,
      "volume":1004
   }
};
*/

const container = document.querySelector('d3fc-canvas');

const xScale = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(fc.extentDate().accessors([d => d.date])(data));

const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(fc.extentLinear().accessors([d => d.high])(data));

const series = fc
  .seriesCanvasCandlestick()
  .xScale(xScale)
  .yScale(yScale);

const r = 1.5;
 
function zoomed(context, width, height, transform) {

  context.save();
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.beginPath();

  for (const d of data) {
    const [x, y] = transform.apply(d); // Problematic line
    console.log(transform.apply(d), d)
    context.moveTo(x + r, y);
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  }

  context.fill();
  context.restore();
}

d3.select(container)
.on('draw', () => {
  series(data);
})
.on('measure', () => {

  const { width, height } = event.detail;

  xScale.range([0, width]);
  yScale.range([height, 0]);

  const ctx = container.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
  series.context(ctx);

  d3.select(ctx.canvas).call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => zoomed(ctx, width, height, d3.event.transform)));
  
  //zoomed(ctx, width, height, d3.zoomIdentity);
});

container.requestRedraw();
```

Answer (score 1):

`d3.event.transform` expects an array of points, not an object. Using `const [x, y] = transform.apply([xScale(d.date), yScale(d.close)]);` gives me the correct coordinates.

I use `xScale` and `yScale` because the transform is normally done by `d3fc` and otherwise, the date is treated as a gigantic number (the number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970).

I recommend changing your plans to either draw the entire thing yourself from the beginning, or use d3fc with the transformed data, because currently, you're looking at two implementations of the same drawing mechanism, which seems wasteful and bug-prone.